# Interpreting statistics notation

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question which follows:

[image]

I understand the first statement with our variable $\overline X_{20}$ representing a sample mean of some size $n$. I'm not sure how to interpret the statement $X_i \sim N(1,2).$

Comment: $\overline X_{20}$ ought to mean the random sample of size $20. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

$X\sim N(1,2)$ usually means $X$ is normally distributed with expected value $1$ and variance $2.$

The normal distribution with expected value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is the probability distribution expressed as follows:
$$
\text{constant}\cdot \frac 1 \sigma \cdot e^{-(1/2)\Big((x-\mu)/\sigma\Big)^2} \,dx
$$
This "constant" has whatever value it takes to make this a probability density function, meaning it makes the integral equal to $1$. It turns out to be $1/\sqrt{2\pi}.$

Comment: If we didn't know $X\sim N(1,2)$, would the sampling distribution of X still be approximated by the normal distribution? My hunch was no, because n is small.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the sampling distribution of $\overline X,$ the sample mean. With fairly symmetric distributions, $20$ is enough to conclude that the sampling distribution of $\overline X$ is approximately normal, but with very skewed distributions it is not. For example, if $\Pr(X_i=0) = 1/100$ and $\Pr(X_i=1) = 99/100$ then the mean of a sample of size $20$ would not be close to normally distributed. With something like an exponential distribution or a uniform distribution or anything else that not too skewed and has finite variance, $20$ is enough for a good rough approximation.